# In Ninject, is this where I would use a child scope?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an WebAPI project using Ninject 3.  About 99% of the time, my injections are in the Request scope, using the Ninject.Web.WebApi extensions.

However, I have a case where I will need to get a Transient-scoped version of an type that is normally injected with Request scope.  Ideally, all of its injections would also become Transient (or at least of an isolated scope).

So I was thinking that there should be some way to use a Factory pattern for this, but I'm not sure how to configure it:

So my class, let's just call it Frog, is registered as .InRequestScope(), because most of the time, that's how I want my Frogs.

But in this one place, I really need to get new, not shared frogs because I'm doing something in parallel.

So, I was thinking Factory Pattern, where I'd have a FrogFactory, and when I call `FrogFactory.Create`, it uses Ninject to resolve a Frog, but it's a new, unique Frog instance every time you call FrogFactory.Create();

(note that Frog still needs to have a `.InRequestScope()` binding as well, for all those places where I share my frogs).

Now, my Frog also has injections, so I'd prefer that my FrogFactory still use Ninject to resolve the Frog, rather than just newing up one by hand.

How would I set that up? (or is there some Ninject conditional binding magic that gets me around the factory pattern?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are likely looking for the `.WhenXxx()` conditional binding methods. you will need some criteria to differentiate the Transient scoped Frog consumers from the rest, which you use in your conditional binding, such as the class name, an attribute applied to the class, an attribute applied to the constructor parameter, etc.

then your bindings will look something like:

```
Bind<IFrog>().To<MyTransientFrog>()
    .WhenClassHas<TransientAttribute>()
    .InTransientScope();

Bind<IFrog>().To<MyRequestFrog>()
    .InRequestScope();
```

If none of the provided methods fit your use case, you can call the generic `.When()` and provide a predicate to determine the condition.

Note that you will also need to specify conditional bindings on any dependency that gets injected into `MyTransientFrog` for them to also be transient, if they aren't already.

```
Bind<IFrogDependency>().To<MyTransientFrogDependency>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<MyTransientFrog>()
    .InTransientScope();
```

*(transient scope is the default and implied in plain bindings, but shown here for clarity)*